# Почему не применяются стики к тексту input type=email который выбираю из всплывающих подсказок?

Tags: html, css, ecmascript-6

После того как я получаю ответ от сервера с ошибкой. Я присваиваю

И в нем задаю цвет текста красный и бордер красный. Но бордер применяется, а текст если я выбираю из всплывающей подсказки, не применяется

[image: На картинке пример всплывающей подсказки о которой я пишу]

после получения ответа от сервера выглядит так
[image: после получения ответа от сервера]

Если я просто без подсказки ввожу текст, то к нему применяется, как сделать чтобы и к тексту в подсказке тоже применилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте к стилям

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #ff0000;
}
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #ff0000;
}
```